# Pebble - Override ScrollLayer's select button callback function

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I'm trying to implement a button action that displays text on my ScrollLayer when the Select button is pressed. I used:

```
scroll_layer_set_click_config_onto_window(scrollLayer, window);
```

to set the BUTTON_UP and BUTTON_DOWN callback functions automatically (to scroll). So then I want to set a BUTTON_SELECT callback function. I wrote these two functions:

```
//Performs an action whenver the 'select' button is pressed
void select_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *ctx) {
    text_layer_set_text(textLayer, "You pressed select");
}

//Links the select button to a function, select_click_handler
void click_config_provider(void *ctx) {
    window_single_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_SELECT, select_click_handler);
}
```

And in my initializer I have:

```
void init() {
    window = window_create();
    window_set_window_handlers(window, (WindowHandlers) {
        .load = window_load,
        .unload = window_unload,
    });
    window_set_click_config_provider(window, click_config_provider);
    window_stack_push(window,true);
}
```

When I run this, it compiles and installs on the watch just fine, however, when I hit the select button, nothing happens. When I comment out `scroll_layer_set_click_config_onto_window(scrollLayer, window);`
it works like it is supposed to.

Is there a way to override the select button callback without having to comment out the above line?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple workaround using `scroll_layer_set_callbacks()` function here:

http://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/11432/scroll-layer-set-callbacks

Answer (score 1):

Now you can find it in Pebble official document(SDK 2.0).

ScrollLayer // Pebble Developers
http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/User_Interface/Layers/ScrollLayer/

The SELECT button can be configured by installing a click configuration provider using scroll_layer_set_callbacks().